# How to select all entries of an MYSQL db beginning with a string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select all db entries that contains a specific string at the beginning. That's my code at the moment:

```php
$keyword = htmlspecialchars($_POST["keyword"]);
$keyword = str_replace(" ","",$keyword);

if($keyword != ""){

    $db = new Database("localhost","root","","test");
    $db->connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username LIKE '".$keyword."%'";
    $res = $db->execCommand($query);
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    if($res["username"] != ""){
        echo json_encode(array_values($res));
    }
    $db->disconnect();
}
```

It works fine but the array/json contains only one entry of the db.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly you are only calling `$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);` once, so you only get one row back.

Second, you are overwriting the `$res` result set with the array of the first row, so you will run into problems if you tried to read more rows.

You need to add a while loop and give your variables unique names:

```
$keyword = htmlspecialchars($_POST["keyword"]);
$keyword = str_replace(" ","",$keyword);

if($keyword != ""){
    $db = new Database("localhost","root","","test");
    $db->connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username LIKE '".$keyword."%'";
    $res = $db->execCommand($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        if($row["username"] != ""){
            echo json_encode(array_values($row));
        }
    }

    $db->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: thank your realy much :)